# How to use Parse server without MongoDb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I only need to use Parse sever cloud functions, How can I run parse server without mongodB

Comment: You need to connect to some database (mongo or postgres) anyways. There are some data, like the application schema, users, that even features like Cloud Code depend on. If you just need to create an endpoint, it might be better to do it directly in an Express.js application, instead of using Parse.

Answer (score 2):

## How to use Parse server without MongoDb ?

> You cannot run a Parse Server instance without a database. For example, Parse store login session into the database

### Two databases available with Parse Server

According to the [documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#database) you have two choices of databases:

- [Postgres](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#postgres)
- [MongoDb](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#mongodb)

So if you do not want to use [MongoDb](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#mongodb) you have to use [Postgres](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#postgres)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542391/comparison-of-mongodb-mysql-and-postgresql) is the difference between theses two databases

### How to switch databases ?

If you want to change your database from a [MongoDb](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#mongodb) to a [Postgres](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#postgres), you just have to change the configuration:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'postgres://my.awesome.postgres.uri',
});
```

Hope my answer help you

Comment: hey I mean I dont need a DB, I only like Cloud funtion of it.. I dont need any DB

Comment: @LeiSen I totally understand, but it’s not possible ... You can simply use express, I had the same issue and use express

Comment: @LeiSen you cannot run a Parse Server instance without a database as Parse store stuff like login session into the database...